# Xdebug in php.ini production performance

Tags: php, xdebug

Is there any performance issues with disabling the xdebug? 
My question if I can disable it and leave it in the php.in or should I remove all section

```
; XDEBUG Extension
[xdebug]
zend_extension ="C:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.16/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.4.0rc2-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="C:/wamp64/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you need to do is comment this line to disable XDEBUG.

```
;zend_extension ="C:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.16/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.4.0rc2-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll"
```

and Xdebug will not be loaded. You can leave all the parameter stuff there, in case you want to re-activate XDEBUG later,

It can make quite an obvious improvement in execution time of php scripts when you remove XDEBUG. I was amazed at quite how much difference the first time I tested it.

Comment: Wow, why was this downvoted... its a straight answer to a straight question!

Comment: @RiggsFolly this tag suffers from chronic serial downvoting.  This answer certainly did not merit the harsh treatment.

Comment: thanks for the answer , how can I check the time of improvments? how can I measure that @RiggsFolly

Comment: Well that's not such an easy one to answer. When I saw the difference for the first time I was testing a simple script that did some math's 1,000,000 iterations of the same calc. Ran it with XDEBUG on and then with it off, the difference was very obvious